# How to pass a JSON array to Spring-MVC?

Tags: java, ajax, json, spring, spring-mvc

How to pass a JSON array to Spring-MVC?

I am trying to find a way to pass a array of objects in JSON to Spring-MVC(Java)..

below is my javascript that setups the two arrays and makes the call:

```
function doAjaxPost() {  

      var inData = {};

      inData.name = ['kurt','johnathan'];
      inData.education = ['GSM','HardKnocks'];

      htmlStr = JSON.stringify(inData);
      alert(htmlStr);

      $.post( contexPath + "/AddUser.htm", inData, function(outData, outStatus){
          alert(outStatus);

      });
};
```

Here is my Java (Spring-MVC) Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/AddUser.htm",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody JsonResponse addUser(@ModelAttribute(value="user") User user, BindingResult result ){
        JsonResponse res = new JsonResponse();
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(result, "name", "Name can not be empty.");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(result, "education", "Educatioan not be empty");
        if(!result.hasErrors()){
            userList.add(user);
            res.setStatus("SUCCESS");
            res.setResult(userList);
        }else{
            res.setStatus("FAIL");
            res.setResult(result.getAllErrors());
        }

        return res;
    }
```

this is the bean I am using:

```
public class User {

    private String name = null;
    private String education = null;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getEducation() {
        return education;
    }
    public void setEducation(String education) {
        this.education = education;
    }

}
```

please let me know the right what to get this working... this is the error I am getting..
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet threw exception
org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'education[]' of bean class [com.raistudies.domain.User]: Property referenced in indexed property path 'education[]' is neither an array nor a List nor a Map; returned value was [[Ljava.lang.String;@6fef3212]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserializing json array in Spring MVC controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613613/deserializing-json-array-in-spring-mvc-controller)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the education property in your JSON is an array, but in your POJO it's a String

If you change

```
private String education = null
```

to

```
private List<String> education = null
```

It should work, you'll also have to do the same thing for the name.

Comment: this shows how to get JSON object from the controller to the page but I need to find out how to pass a array of objects from the page BACK to the controller

Comment: it did not work.. still getting the error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "

Comment: this wasn't the error for this question, why you should repost the same question under a different name.